# Probability a hypercube is non-empty in a uniformly distributed point set in higher dimensions

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

Before I start, I just want to say I'm actually a computer science student and thus, my maths is not very strong so please feel free to make your explanations more detailed via adding additional links or comments and such.

#### The Scenario

I am randomly generating $N$ points in $D$ dimensional space (let's call this the data set) and I also generate a test set of points. The values are generated with uniform probability distribution and range from $[0,1]$. So let's say $D$ = 5, then an example point would be $(0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 0.9, 0.7)$.

I want to determine the probability $p$ that there exists at least one point in the data set which lies within a hypercube of side length $2e$ centred at $Q$, where $Q$ is a point in the test set. In other words, I want an equation relating $p$ and $e$.

#### My thoughts

For a point $Z$ to lie within a hypercube of side $2e$ centred at $Q$, each of its coordinates would need to lie within ${\pm}e$ of each corresponding coordinate of $Q$. For example, if $Q$ =$(Q_1, Q_2, Q_3,...,Q_D)$ and $Z$ = $(Z_1, Z_2, Z_3,...,Z_D)$, for $Z$ to lie within this hypercube, we need:

$Q_1-e{\leq}Z_1{\leq}Q_1+e$

$Q_2-e{\leq}Z_2{\leq}Q_2+e$

... and so on.

Let's rephrase $P(Q_i-e \leq Z_i \leq Q_1+e)$ as $P(|Z_i-Q_i|\leq{e})$. Since $Z_i$ and $Q_i$ are 2 independent uniform variates in $[0,1]$, then:

$P(|Z_i-Q_i|\geq{e}) = (1-e)^2$ ([visual depiction of why](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssHTf.png)) and thus:

$P(|Z_i-Q_i|\leq{e}) = 1-(1-e)^2 = 2e-e^2$

Then the probability that $Z$ lies within the hypercube of $Q$ with coordinates bounded by $[0,1]$ in $D$ dimensions is

= (2e-e^2)^D$.

Of course, the probability will vary with each point since this assumes $Z$ and $Q$ are independently uniformly random (e.g. if your test point $Q$ is $(0, 0)$ at the very corner, then the probability of $Z$ being in the hypercube will be much smaller since much of the hypercube is "cut off" [example of what I mean in 2 dimensional space. The non-shaded area has no points inside it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXu9t.png)) but over a large number of test points, it will average out* (I think this is the problem, please read the bottom).

After testing this, it seems to be accurate. For example with, $D = 2, e = 0.2$, we get $(2(0.2)-0.2^2)^2=0.1296$. If we have $N=100 000$ and a test set of 10 000 points and for each test point, we counted the number of data set points which lied within its hypercube, we'd expect a total count of $0.1296...{\times}10 000{\times}100 000=129 600 000$ points. My test gives me 129 393 108 points.

But what is the probability that the hypercube is non-empty? If $P(k)$ = the probability that $k$ points lie inside the hypercube of side $2e$ centred at a test point $Q$, then a simple binomial gives us:

$P(k)=((2e-e^2)^D)^k(1-(2e-e^2)^D)^{N-k}\binom{N}{k}$

Since $p$ is the probability that there is at least one point in this hypercube:

$p=1-P(0)$

$=1-(1-(2e-e^2)^D)^N$

Subjecting $e$ and we get:

$e=1-\sqrt{1-(1-(1-p)^{\frac{1}{N}})^\frac{1}{D}}$.

#### My Problem

However, this doesn't seem to be correct. As the dimensions go higher, it gets more and more inaccurate. Let's take a data set of $N = 100 000$ and a test set of 10 000 and $p=0.99$. I should be generating around 100 empty hypercubes (1% of 10 000 test points should have no points in the data set within a hypercube of side $2e$ centred at the test point).

For $D=2$, I get $e=0.003399$. This generates 113 empty hypercubes.

For $D=5$, I get $e=0.070334$. This generates 209 empty hypercubes.

For $D=10$, I get $e=0.205269$. This generates 644 empty hypercubes.

#### What I think is wrong

As pointed out below by David K, maybe the events are not independent because the each test point $Q$ is fixed when testing against all N points in the data set. Therefore, binomial probability would not apply to this analysis since we assumed 2 independently random points Z and Q but in this case, each test point Q would be fixed for multiple Z.

Intuitively, I think I need to also analyse the distribution of the probability that Z lies in the hypercube of Q for a fixed Q or to analyse something about the "cut-off" areas for when Q is closer to the corners/edges.

Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: I haven't entered into the detail of your computations, but it looks to me that if you should restrict you quest to the $D=2$case in order to detect the origin of problem. It would be simpler for you and for people who can help.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error in the calculated probability is that the cases where
$Q$ is in a corner **do not** "average out" over a large number of test points.

Let $d(A,B)$ be the $L_\infty$ distance between points $A$ and $B$,
so that $d(A,B)<e$ means $A$ is in the hypercube of side $2e$ centered at $B$.
Then for a large number of test points $Z,$ $Z',$ $Z'', \ldots,$
you are dealing with the events
$d(Z,Q)<e,$ $d(Z',Q)<e,$ $d(Z'',Q)<e,$ and so forth.
The probability of each of these events is $(2e-e^2)^D,$ as you found,
but the events are not independent.
So the rest of your calculations are based on a false assumption.